# List first or null item

Tags: c#, .net

I'm getting a list and I want the first item or null value. So I made this `var foundedItem= db.FindMyItem(new Dictionary<string, string> { { "Name", name} })?[0];`
I have an error just on this line. It return "Index out of range" but I'm using "?" so it need to return me null value right ?

Comment: What is the content of FindMyItem?  What is db?  Too many missing details here.  Show your code and at minimum a MVCE.

Comment: So you're asking how to display a *tutorial*? A *splash screen* with news? Seriously, with so many downvotes you should realize the questions you post are bad. It's not the use of English, it's the question itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Question :

```
var foundedItem= db.FindMyItem(new Dictionary<string, string> { { "Name", name} })?[0]
```

---

```
function Dictionary<string, string> FindMyItem(string Id){
    return db.Items.Find(Id);
}
```

With this approach you do not want the list :D

Answer (score 1):

use LINQ query.

```
var result = myListItem.FirstOrDefault();
```